# MongoDB Script to update field in select documents with query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to write a simple script where you have an array of numbers that will be used to update the document that has that specific number within the jersey object, and that document's sponsor within the jersey object will be updated. Below I have the keys of the collection named "athletes", within a database named "sports", and than the script I have thus far. The changes array will be a list of the numbers, and than I want to use that and update the sponsor field to "Nike". Now at the moment I am getting this error, but I have been adding/removing brackets and to no avail at the moment. I was also curious if I should be using single or double quotes in certain places, since I have looked at examples and have seen both.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

**Keys**

```
firstName - String
lastName - String
jersey - Object
   number - String 
   sponsor - String
```

Note: each document has a unique ‘number’ within ‘jersey’ object

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('sports');

var changes = [
  "23",
  "8"
];

for(var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
    db.athletes.update({
      "jersey": {
      "number": changes[i],
    },
  }
  {'$set': {"sponsor": 'Nike'} }
 );}
```

Comment: Did you try using dot notation ? `for(var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {db.athletes.update({
      "jersey.number": changes[i]
  },
  {$set: {"sponsor": 'Nike'} })}`. This is how you can access the embedded object fields. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: Thanks Veeram I didn't know I could use dot notation that makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: When I changed to dot notation I still got the same syntax error but it got resolved when I removed the comma after changes[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command:

```
      var changes=["23","8"];

      for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
          db.athletes.update({
              "jersey.number": changes[i]
          }, {
              $set: {
                  "jersey.sponsor": "NIKE"
              }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have posted it after I got it, though this works. I fixed it after Veeram's comment, my main issue was the syntax error due to the comma I had directly after changes[i]; but I also used dot notation